# Canvas to be same height to left column

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am new to JavaScript and I found a codepen which allowed me to create a canvas with confettis falling with javascript. I added the javascript to my project but it seems that the canvas height to way too long. I want the canvas height to be the same as the column on the left (Body). It seems that the canvas' height is set using Javascript but I am still a beginner to the language and hence not sure how to modify it to the way I want. Would appreciate any help thanks.

```
 <canvas id="confeti" class="active" width="100%" height="100%">

 </canvas>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gomLNV

Answer (score 0):

one solution would be to call this onload :

```
function fixSize(){

  var confeti = document.getElementById("confeti");  
  var leftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");  
  confeti.style.height = leftSide.clientHeight + 'px';

}
```

Ofcourse you have to add the id `leftSide` to the element which you want to use as max height.

To be fair this is really ugly and simple.

Comment: i think your problem could be solved with css. I just tried some stuff with `display : flex` and it works really well.

Answer (score 0):

code similar to what spaceninja posted.

i didn't mess with any of your css, its just three lines of js, close to what he responded with:

```
let b = document.getElementById('b');
let c = document.getElementById('confeti');
c.style.height = b.clientHeight+'px';
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJvNQb

Comment: I think he still has to put these lines into a function so he can call it when canvas is ready.

Comment: no he doesn't.  since the markup is static in this case, as long as script is called in the body it should be fine.

check the codepen i dropped. works great there.

Comment: if he wished to put his js in a script tag before the body, then he would need to though.